# Подскажите скрипт Way Poin Page Jquery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Для одно-страничного сайта, чтобы по клику на меню плавно перемещал на раздел страницы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/
Простое API
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".menu a").click(function() {
         var cls = $(this).attr('data-cls'); // в каждом пункте меню в атрибуте data-cls можешь хранить название класса, к которому нужно сделать прокрутку
         var destination = $("." + cls).offset().top;

         $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: destination});
 });
```